# Establishing IMAP connection using PHP fsockopen()

Tags: php, networking

Aim : Building a class to connect to an `IMAP` server and send `commands`

Here's What I have done :

1. Class `connection` takes `host`,`port` and an optional one `timeout` as parameters.
2. Defined a `__constructor()` function to make a new connection using `fsockopen()`.
3. Defined a `command()` function to give commands to successfully connected `IMAP` server.

There is no problem with the `__constructor()` function. But the main problem is with the `command()` function. I was unable to `echo` any command I got from the server after I give the login command.

This entire process might be useless to make IMAP connections but I need for learning. So, please help me and thanks in advance.

Following is the PHP Code

```
class connection {
  public $pointer;
  function __construct(...$args){
    if (count($args) < 2){
      echo "\033[01;31m Error: Insufficient number of arguments given \033[0m";
      return;
    }
    elseif (count($args) == 2){
      if (!(is_numeric($args[1]))){
        echo "\033[01;31m Error: Invalid 2nd argument \033[0m";
        die();
      }
      elseif (!(is_string($args[0]))){
        echo "\033[01;31m Error: Invalid 1st argument \033[0m";
        die();
      }
      else{
        $fp = @fsockopen($args[0],$args[1]);
        if (!($fp)){
          echo "\033[01;31m Failed: Cannot connect to the host ".$args[0]." via port ".$args[1]."\033[0m";
          die();
        }
        else{
          echo "Success: Connection established to the host ".$args[0]." via port ".$args[1];
          $this->pointer = $fp;
          return $fp;
        }
      }
    }
    elseif (count($args) == 3){
      if (!(is_numeric($args[1]))){
        echo "\033[01;31m Error: Invalid 2nd argument given to function: __construct() of connection() \033[0m";
        die();
      }
      elseif (!(is_string($args[0]))){
        echo "\033[01;31m Error: Invalid 1st argument given to function: __construct() of connection() \033[0m";
        die();
      }
      elseif (!(is_numeric($args[2]))){
        echo "\033[01;31m Error: Invalid 3rd argument given to function: __construct() of connection() \033[0m";
        die();
      }
      else{
        $fp = @fsockopen($args[0],$args[1],$args[2]);
        if (!($fp)){
          echo "\033[01;31m Failed: Cannot connect to the host ".$args[0]." via port ".$args[1]."\033[0m";
          die();
        }
        else{
          echo "Success: Connection established to the host ".$args[0]." via port ".$args[1]."\n";
          $this->pointer = $fp;
          return $fp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  function command($string){
    if (!(is_string($string))){
      echo "\033[01;31m Error: Invalid argument given to function: command()\033[0m";
      die();
    }
    else{
      $send = fputs($this->pointer,$string);
      $return = fgets($this->pointer);
      echo $return;
    }
  }
}
$point = new connection("imap.gmail.com",993,30);
$point->command("a00001 login ****** ********");

?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `fgets` returns `FALSE`, because an error happened. May you should handle this and try it again.

Comment: @martin is there any error in the code?